# Add Subscribers to Discussion via Active Collab API

Tags: php, api, rest, activecollab

We are currently customizing our Active Collab 5.6.4 Self Hosted installation. I'm trying to add subscribers for a discussion through the api - I'm using the following api method

***PUT*** /subscribers/task/1

(see https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/utilities/notifications/subscribers.html)

But the examples in there are only for adding subscribers to tasks - how do I add subscribers to discussions? I tried using

***PUT*** /subscribers/discussions/1

That does not do anything, also this does not yield any error so I think there must be a method somehow already. Does anybody know which method should be used to add subscribers to discussions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribers can be added by POST-ing a list of new subscribers to `/subscribers/discussion/:discussion_id`. You need to POST a JSON object wtih a list of subscribers, where each subscriber can be:

1. An ID of existing user in the system,
2. An email address of a user,
3. An array, where first element is user's name and second is user's address.

An example payload:

```
{
    "s1": 12,
    "s2": "anon3@activecollab.com",
    "s3": [
        "Another Anonymous",
        "anon4@activecollab.com"
    ]
}
```

POST adds subscribers to existing subscribers. PUT on the other hand will replace all existing subscribers with the new list. DELETE clears the subscribers list.

Comment: Works perfectly, just a simple "s" too much. Thanks for pointing that out. Please add this to the documentation if possible